# Passing Different Length List Parameters to R Function

Tags: r, list, function

I have a user-written function that I want to be able to pass both lists and single parameter arguments to. The lists can be different lengths. The following is a simplified example, where I combined the lists using expand.grid and use map:

```
fake_dat <-  as.data.frame(matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE))

one_lst <- c("a","b")
two_lst <- c("aa","bb")
all_lst <- expand.grid(one_lst, two_lst)

with(all_lst, Map(function(var1, var2, dat, x) {
  print(var1)
  print(var2)
  print(dat[[x]])
}, Var1, Var2, dat=fake_dat, x="V2"))
```

Using it this way I get the following error:

```
Error in (function (cond) : 
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'print': subscript out of bounds
```

However, if I embed the single parameters within list, it seems to work:

```
with(all_lst, Map(function(var1, var2, dat, x) {
  print(var1)
  print(var2)
  print(dat[[x]])
}, Var1, Var2, dat=list(fake_dat), x=list("V2")))
```

Is this the appropriate way to use map for my scenario...or is there a better way to accomplish passing some lists (potentially of varying lengths) and some single parameter arguments to a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but the error is because `fake_dat` has length = 2 (number of columns in the `data.frame`), so `Map` passes those columns to the function one at a time. When the first column is passed, "V2" is out of bounds. This is why wrapping `fake_dat` with `list()` resolves the error--the whole `data.frame` is passed to the function because `list(fake_dat)` has length 1.  (Wrapping "V2" with `list()` does nothing here.)

```
with(all_lst, Map(function(var1, var2, dat, x) {
  print(var1)
  print(var2)
  print(dat[[x]])
}, Var1, Var2, dat=list(fake_dat), x="V2"))
```

Note that if the vector arguments of `Map` are of different lengths, the shorter arguments are recycled.

Comment: ...thanks for the response. I guess I was wondering, is surrounding fake_dat within list() the correct/best way to handle that argument in this scenario...or is there some other way to set up a function that can handle multiple list arguments, but also handle an argument that is NOT a list and should be 'recycled' as you stated.

Comment: Yes, you wrap `fake_dat` with `list()` because you don't want to pass the individual columns to the function. But you *do* want to pass the individual elements of `all_lst$Var1` and `all_lst$Var2`, so those are not wrapped in `list()`.